# .net Dictionary To JSON object Nested

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

With Newtonsoft, is there a way to create complete JSON from a string.  For example:

```
Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
d.Add("test.nested","value")
d.Add("test.nested2", "value2")

Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l.Data)
```

I want the output to be:

```
{
   "test": {
     "nested":"value", 
     "nested2", "value2"
   }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you with the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a couple of helper methods to convert the dictionary to a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) hierarchy and then take the JSON from that.  This implementation will handle any number of dots in the keys so you can nest as deeply as you want:

```
Class JsonHelper
    Public Shared Function DictionaryToJson(dict As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As String
        Dim root As New JObject()
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dict
            FindOrAdd(root, kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
        Next
        Return root.ToString()
    End Function

    Private Shared Function FindOrAdd(parent As JObject, key As String, value As String) As JObject
        If key Is Nothing Then Return parent
        Dim i As Integer = key.IndexOf(".")
        If i > -1 Then
            Dim obj As JObject = FindOrAdd(parent, key.Substring(0, i), Nothing)
            Return FindOrAdd(obj, key.Substring(i + 1), value)
        End If
        Dim prop As JProperty = parent.Property(key)
        If value Is Nothing Then
            Dim child As JObject
            If prop Is Nothing Then
                child = New JObject()
                parent.Add(key, child)
            Else If prop.Value.Type = JTokenType.Object
                child = DirectCast(prop.Value, JObject)
            Else
                Throw New JsonException("The key """ + parent.Path + "." + key + """ already has a value.")
            End If
            Return child
        Else
            If prop Is Nothing Then
                parent.Add(key, New JValue(value))
                Return parent
            Else
                Throw New JsonException("The key """ + parent.Path + "." + key + """ already has a value.")
            End If
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

You can use it like this (where `d` is the dictionary in your question):

```
Dim output As String = JsonHelper.DictionaryToJson(d)
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eu6YMv

Comment: This only works to one level but with a few modifications can work recursively.

Comment: Actually this method is already recursive and will go deeper than one level.  I added another test case to the fiddle to demonstrate.  However, you have to make sure not to try to add a subkey to a key which already has a value that is not an object.  I missed this case before; now it will throw a JsonException with an appropriate message (instead of an InvalidCastException)

Answer (score 1):

What about using something like a dictionary of dictionaries? This way, you'd have the required structure ready to use. If so, you can simply do:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
dict.Add("test", New Dictionary(Of String, String))
dict("test").Add("nested1", "value1")
dict("test").Add("nested2", "value2")
Dim output As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict)
```